# How to make multiple answers correct to a question of a quiz program?

Tags: python

Here's an example:

```
questions = ["what colour are apples?", "what colour are bananas?"]
answers = ["red", "yellow"]

for question in range(len(questions)):
    answer = input(questions[question]).lower()
    if answer == answers[question]:
        print ("correct")
```

Here, for apple, I want to make red as well as green be accepted as the correct answer. How can I make it so?

I tried `answers = ["red" or "green", "yellow"]` instead but it didn't work and only accepted red as the correct one. I tried it with `and` too but then it only accepted green as the correct one.

Comment: Try `"red" or "green"` and `"red" and "green"` in the Python interpreter and you'll see why you get that behaviour.

Comment: Make each element of `answers` a `tuple` (`[("red", "green"), ("yellow",)]`) and use `if answer in answers[question]:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate it in a better way so, it's more clear and convenient

```
questions = ["What colour are apples?", "What colour are bananas?"]
answers = [("red", "green"), ("yellow",)]

for question,correct_answer in zip(questions,answers):
    answer = input(question).strip().lower()
    if answer in correct_answer:
        print ("correct")
```

Results from `and` and `or`:

```
>>> "red" or "blue"
'red'
>>> "red" and "blue"
'blue'
```

This resulting in:

```
>>> "red" == ("red" and "blue")
False
>>> "blue" == ("red" and "blue")
True
>>> "red" == ("red" or "blue")
True
>>> "blue" == ("red" or "blue")
False
```